# Populating a combobox in ProWindow SDK C# ArcGIS Pro Addin

Tags: c#, combo-box, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am trying to populate a combobox in a ProWindow item in Visual Studio based on the Layer list in TOC. I add the combobox using the Toolbox pane. The Combobox is viewable but I can't seem to find a way of adding my layer list based on what layers are already in the TOC. The code below is what I have so far.

```
public partial class ProWindow1 : ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls.ProWindow
    {
        public ProWindow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void UpdateCombo()
        {
            
            List<FeatureLayer> featureLayerList = 
         MapView.Active.Map.GetLayersAsFlattenedList().OfType<FeatureLayer>().ToList();
           
            // Add feature layer names to the combobox
            await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
            {
                var featCursor = featureLayerList.ToList();          
                   
                    featCursor.ToString();

            });
//I think this is where I mess up.
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing some examples here is how to populate a combobox which has been added using the ProWindow xaml design,

```
  public partial class ProWindow1 : ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls.ProWindow
    {
        // Reference to the ComboBox in XAML
        private System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox _myComboBox;
        public ProWindow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            // Assuming you have named your ComboBox in XAML as "myComboBox"
            _myComboBox = FindName("myComboBox") as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;

                PopulateComboBox();

        }

        private async void PopulateComboBox()
        {
                // Get the current map
                var map = MapView.Active.Map;

                if (map == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No active map found.");
                    return;
                }
             

                // Iterate through all layers in the map
                foreach (var layer in map.GetLayersAsFlattenedList())
                {
                    // Check if the layer is a FeatureLayer
                    if (layer is FeatureLayer featureLayer)
                    {
                        // Access the name of the FeatureLayer
                        string layerName = layer.Name;

                        // Add items to the ComboBox


                        _myComboBox.Items.Add(layerName);
                    }
                }
        
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample in the SDK documentation that shows how to add the layers in a map to a combobox.

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/MVVM-XAML/DockpaneWithLayerFieldSelection